# If $g(x)$ is 1:1, and $g=\{(3,2), (a,0), (-1,b), (1,3)\}$, what is $g^{-1}(g(b))$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, inverse

**Question**

If $g(x)$ is 1:1, and $g=\{(3,2), (a,0), (-1,b), (1,3)\}$, what is $g^{-1}(g(b))$?

I thought that it would just be $b$ but the answer key said that it does not exist.

I was wondering why it doesn't exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that you do not map $b$ to anything since no tuple has $b$ as its first coordinate (only one as it second). So $g(b)$ does not exist. Hence also $g^{-1}(g(b))$. To be precise: A function $f: X \to Y$ is a binary relation $f \subseteq X \times Y$ (with some uniquenessproperty of course), but $b \notin X$.

Comment: But what guarantees here that $b\notin\{3,a,-1,1\}$? I think that here special cases must be discerned. If e.g. $b=1$ then the answer is $1$.

Comment: @drhab Yes, you are right. But nothing is stated about the nature of $a$ or $b$. So it is like a riddle.

Comment: I think the problem to be solved is not well-posed. No blame for the OP but for the one who composed this problem.

Comment: @drhab Yes also right. I just wanted to give an idea, why it might be wrong.

Comment: @drhab $b$ cannot be $3$ as $g(-1)=b$ and $g(1)=3$.  But I would have thought that you can deduce $a\not \in \{1,3\}$, and that $b=-1$ could be  possible if $a\not=-1$, that  $b=1$ could be possible if $a\not=-1$, and that $b=a \not \in \{-1,0,1,2,3\}$ could be possible.  I think all of these possibilities would lead to $g^{-1}(g(b))=b$